# position:fixed for a floated div

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

I have a div that is floated left in a wrapper container.  Now I want the div to stay in one spot when the page is scrolled.  So I tried position:fixed, but this ruins the other css properties of the div.

I've tried using javascript aswell:

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
    $("#id").css({'top',$(window).scrollTop() + 'px'});
});
```

That javascript isn't doing anything.  Is there any other way to do this, I still want to keep the float:left property intact.

Thanks

Comment: Could you create a fiddle of your example?

Comment: You can't really combine floated positioning and absolue/fixed positioning without unpredictable results happening across browsers. For your case here I think you'd be best to stick to fixed positioning.

Comment: what @jQuerybeast said. From what you've said it doesn't seem to make any sense to set float:left... maybe there is a better way of achieving what you want but more context is needed.

Comment: I have a main div container: mainwrapper.  In mainwrapper there are two columns made from divs.  One is float:left the other is float:right.  I need the left column to have fixed position.

Comment: Yeah and why does it need float:left rather than say left:0px for example?

Comment: My layout was already complete and changing the column to left:0px and position:fixed is creating a lot of weird behaviour.  Is there no Javascript fix for this?  Is there something wrong with the js I have above?

Answer (score 0):

See all the elements with different position attributes form different layers. So you have to adjust other elements when you keep this element 'position:fixed'

You have to keep empty space for this div forever, and it will stay fixed there even when you scroll your page.

See this link for better understanding

http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-fixed-position.php